# How to solve $1/2 \sin(2x) + \sin(x) + 2 \cos(x) + 2 = 0$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve trigonomtry function involving $\sin x \cos x$ and $\sin 2x$:

$$\frac{1}{2} \sin(2x) + \sin(x) + 2 \cos(x) + 2 = 0. $$

Comment: You last three lines should be removed. "help me," "thank you" etc should not be part of the question. The way you can show appreciation is by voting answers (good: up & poor: down), accepting an answer, replying to clarification comments, and most importantly, showing what you tried & where you got stuck.

Comment: @JenniferDylan Ok, but politeness should never be discouraged :-)

Comment: After your several questions in trigonometry, it'd be nice if you showed some self-work, some insights, ideas, effort in solving them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using the identity $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$ we have
$$ \sin x \cos x + \sin x + 2\cos x + 2 = 0$$
Factor
$$ (1 + \cos x) \sin x + 2(1 + \cos x) = 0 \\ 
(1 + \cos x)(2 + \sin x) = 0
$$
So either $1 + \cos x = 0$ or $2 + \sin x = 0.$
Solve for $x$ in each case.

Comment: the answer is x = 0 rad and 2 pi rad

Comment: @dramasea No, that's not correct. First, $\sin x = -2$ has no real solutions. Why? Well because $\sin x \in [-1, 1].$ Second case: if $\cos x = -1,$ then what is $x$? Draw the unit circle and think about it. Also, please note that if $\theta$ is a solution, then $\theta + 2\pi, \theta + 4\pi, \theta + 6\pi, \dots$ are also solutions.

Comment: thanks!!! can u help me solve $$\tan2x-\sin4x = 0$$

Comment: @dramasea it's a customary of math.SE to post separate threads for different questions, so please go ahead & post a new question. I (or other users) will try to help you.

Comment: here's the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183694/how-to-solve-tan2x-sin4x-0  tq